# String to date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have strings that are supposed to be dates in the following format: `01.02.19` (this would be 01 February 2019)

I am trying to convert these string to real dates, so I am doing the following:

```
var parts ='01.02.19'.split('.');

var mydate = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
```

The result from the above is Mar 18 1901 while it should be Feb 01 2018.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: javascript month is zero based. 0 = Jan 1 = Feb etc.

Comment: see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for example, this should be `new Date(year, monthIndex, day);`, note also that `19` is 1919..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` constructor takes the largest to smallest times, so it starts with year. The year needs to be the full four digits and months are zero-indexed so February would be month `1`.

To fix your issue, swap the parts, decrease `parts[1]` by `1` and prefix `parts[2]` with `20`

```js
var parts ='01.02.19'.split('.');
var date = new Date("20" + parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);

console.log(date.toGMTString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If including the wonderful [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is an option, you can do :

`moment("01.02.19", "DD.MM.YY").format("MMM DD YYYY") // Feb 01 2019`

Comment: I'm never a fan of including a JS library for a single feature, but I'll admit that MomentJS' date parsing is pretty sweet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following array to extract the month name also changing the order of parts in new Date like this:

```
new Date(`${parts[1]}/${parts[0]}/${parts[2]}`);
```

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var parts ='01.02.19'.split('.');

var mydate = new Date(`${parts[1]}/${parts[0]}/${parts[2]}`); 

console.log(` ${monthNames[mydate.getMonth()] } ${mydate.getDate()} ${mydate.getFullYear()}`)
```